# NETSDK1152 Error for _ViewImports.cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, razor-class-library

After upgrading my WebApp from NET5 to NET6, when trying to push my WebApp to the Azure AppService, I get the NETSDK1152 error:

> Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path:
> C:...\src\ProjA_ViewImports.cshtml,
> C:...\src\ProjB_ViewImports.cshtml,
> C:...\src\ProjC_ViewImports.cshtml

The projects in Question are Razor Class Libraries (Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor"), which all get referenced by a regular Web App (). The files in question are _ViewImport.cshtml files to contain common usings/imports for my Views. They only have their standard properties which never got changed by me (Action -> Content, Copy to Output Directory -> Do not Copy).

Before updating to NET6, everything worked flawlessly, both on my local machine as well as on Azure (both publishing and running the application). After my upgrade to .NET6, I started receiving the error mentioned above.

However, this ONLY occurs when I use the publish functionality (or when the CI/CD is triggered by pushing to the remote git repo). If I use dotnet publish locally, everything seems to be published just fine.

Trying the usual recommendation, of turning off the error (as proposed, for instance, [here](https://www.poppastring.com/blog/fixing-error-netsdk1152-after-upgrading-to-net-6)), did not solve anything for me.

Apart from either getting rid of the _ViewImport.cshtml files altogether, or restructuring the project, I am lost with regards how to potentially solve this issue while keeping the structure as is.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/duplicate-files-in-output):

> The .NET SDK generates a new error (NETSDK1152) in cases where files from different source paths would be copied to the same file path in the publish output. This can happen when a project and its project references include a file with the same name that's included in the publish output.
>
> #### Old Behavior
>
> Both files were copied to the same destination. The second file to be copied overwrote the first file, and which file "won" was mostly arbitrary.
>
> In some cases, the build failed. For example, when trying to create a single-file app, the bundler failed with an  [ArgumentException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception), as shown in the following build output:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(962,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateBundle" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\repro\repro.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(962,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Invalid input specification: Found multiple entries with the same BundleRelativePath [C:\repro\repro.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(962,5): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.GenerateBundle(IReadOnlyList`1 fileSpecs) [C:\repro\repro.csproj]
```

> #### New behavior
>
> Starting in .NET 6, MSBuild removes duplicate files that are copied to the publish folder if both the source and destination are the same. If there are any remaining duplicates, a  `NETSDK1152`  error is generated and lists the files that are duplicated.
>
> #### Reason for change
>
> Duplicate files in the publish output sometimes caused build breaks or unpredictable behavior.
>
> #### Recommended action
>
> - Ideally, you should update your project to avoid situations where multiple files with the same name are copied to the publish output.
>   The error message includes the name of the duplicate file. Some causes
>   for duplicate files include:
>
>   - An ASP.NET Core project that references an ASP.NET Core web service, and each has its own  *appsettings.json*  file.
>   - A project item where  `CopyToOutputDirectory`  is unnecessarily set to  `Always`.
>
>   [Binary log files](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/documentation/wiki/Providing-Binary-Logs.md)
>   can be useful for finding the cause of the duplicated files.
> - Alternatively, you can set the  [ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#erroronduplicatepublishoutputfiles)
>   property to  `false`.