# NETSDK1152 Multiple output files error for _ViewImports.cshtml files when publishing ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

Recently I migrated my asp.net core 3.1 web app to NET6. Before migration, I didn't have this kind of problems. My web app has several projects (DLL) and some of them have Views and Controllers due to requirements. I marked those projects as Skd.Razor as shown below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I configured Startup to recognize those controllers and views by using application parts:

[image]

Each project has its own _ViewImports.cshtml including Main Project SicotX:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem comes out when I'm trying to publish the application, compilation is generating the following error

[image]

_ViewImports.cshtml is causing conflicts in the output path in both projects except the main SiotX project.

I need to use _ViewImports into those projects so I need your help or guide how to overcome this issue is blocking me, or maybe is it possible to use a unique _ViewImports.cshtml and share with all projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET SDK 6.0.100, the .NET SDK generates a new error (NETSDK1152) in cases where files from different source paths would be copied to the same file path in the publish output. This can happen when a project and its project references include a file with the same name that's included in the publish output.

Please visit [Generate error for duplicate files in publish output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/duplicate-files-in-output) to get detailed information.

I found some suggestions that could help you fix this issue.

1. Add code below in *.csproj files to all of your projects.

```html
<ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
```

2. Exclude the problematic files from copying to the output folder.

Add the following lines to your **common.props** (located in the root directory of your solution):

```html
<Content Remove="file_name"/>
<None Include="file_name">
  <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

References:

1. [Publish error: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69919694/10309381)
2. [NETSDK1152 Error for _ViewImports.cshtml files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70133558/10309381)