# I Get an Error When I Publish the Web Application to a Local Folder in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022. When I publish a Web Application or Web Api project to the local site in ASP.NET Core 7.0 version, I receive the error whose screenshot and details I shared in the error log.

However, when I "Exclude From Project" the appsettings.json file in the project, I do not receive the same error. Is there a different approach other than doing "Exclude From Project"? I'm trying to understand this, if anyone knows, can you explain the logic of the error detail?

**Error Log :**

```
Connecting to C:\Users\enesg\Desktop\LocalPublish...
SM.WebUI -> C:\Users\enesg\source\StreamLogic\src\SM.WebUI\bin\Release\net7.0\SM.WebUI.dll
            C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ConflictResolution.targets(112,5): Error NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path: 
           
        C:\Users\enesg\source\StreamLogic\SM.Web.Api\appsettings.Development.json,
        C:\Users\enesg\source\StreamLogic\src\SM.WebUI\appsettings.Development.json, C:\Users\enesg\source\StreamLogic\SM.Web.Api\appsettings.json,
C:\Users\enesg\source\StreamLogic\src\SM.WebUI\appsettings.json.
            
1>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
```

**Visual Studio Error Screen :**

[image]

**As mentioned in the error detail, there is not more than one output path. I share my publish configuration details**

Could it be that because both WebApi and WebApplication appsettings.json are present in the same project, it is seen multiple times?

Thank you for your ideas and support.

[image: publish configuration details]

Is there a different approach in a WebApplication project other than the "Exclude from Project" process? I'm trying to understand this, can anyone explain the logic of the error detail?

Comment: You might be able to customize the Release configuration but I'm unsure how exactly.  Or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71331168/netsdk1152-multiple-output-files-error-for-viewimports-cshtml-files-when-publis

Comment: Have you try this recommended action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/duplicate-files-in-output#recommended-action ?